# why? does not detect the media

Tags: css, media-queries

I have problems with the media-query, it detects me well the first but when they are less than 768px it no longer detects the average

this are my media-querys.

```
@media  screen and (max-width:1920px){
#log {
bottom: 36%;
left: 35%;
  }
 }

@media screen and (max-width:1440px){
#log {

left: 41%;
width: 57%;
bottom: 30%;

}

#img2 {
width: 100%;
}
}
 @media screen and (max-width:1024px){
#log {
left: 61%;
width: 72%;
bottom: 30%;
 }
#img2 {
width: 100%;
  }
 }

  @media  screen and (max-width:765px){  /***** this is the one that does not work
#Table_01 {
margin-top: -12%;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The last media query just works when the width of the screen is equal or lower than 765px not 768px. Also need to close the comment with */

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) { /* this is the one that does not work */
    #Table_01 {
        margin-top: -12%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the width of the screen you are testing on?

Comment: Inspect the element #Table_01, and check if the style is there and the width of the screen is equal or less than 765px. Also in the code of your question you need to close the comment width */

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: **[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9p3qos2f/)**

```css
#Table_01 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   #Table_01 {
     margin-top: -12%;
   }
}
```

```html
<table id="Table_01"></table>
```

**Note:** in some `@media` questions you have ***2*** spaces, try to use one only to avoid any possible issue.